# Output array items as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array here - https://jsfiddle.net/nx75Lcmd/1/ - which is showing the second item in each group - i.e b & e. When I print out the results in a console.log it loops over the results and shows the results fine but when I try to output the results in a div it just shows the last item. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

```
var myStringArray = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"]
];

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myStringArray[i][1];
  console.log(myStringArray[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: You are assigning `innerHTML` property everytime which means, everytime it gets recreated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `.innerHTML` will override all the HTML in your div, it doesn't append to it. Instead, you could create a global string which your append to in your `for` loop, and then set that as your `innerHTML` once your loop is complete.

See working example below:

```js
var myStringArray = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"]
];

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
var outputHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  outputHTML += myStringArray[i][1];
  //console.log(myStringArray[i][1]);
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = outputHTML;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

By creating an external string you only need to do `.innerHTML` once (which is an expensive operation), thus helping minimize the amount of work your code needs to do.

Comment: +1 for showing a string being built up in the loop instead of updating the DOM upon each loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = myStringArray[i][1];` overrides the text every time,

You can add a `+` infront of the `=` that means it will `add` to the existing text and not `replace`.

like:   `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += myStringArray[i][1];`

**Demo**

```js
var myStringArray = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"]
];

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += myStringArray[i][1];
  console.log(myStringArray[i][1]);
}
```

```html
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So the + adds entries and doesn't overwrite them. Thanks again